# Is the complex symmetric part of a $2\times2$ normal matrix always normal?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I want to prove (or disprove) that, for a normal matrix $A\in\mathbb{C}^{2x2}$ (so that $AA^\ast=A^\ast A$), the sum $A+A^T$ is (or isn't) normal.

I know that for $3\times3$ normal matrices, $A+A^T$ isn't normal, but for the $2\times2$ case, when I try to come with a counterexample I do not manage to make it.

Comment: Is there a difference between $*$ and $T$ here?  Are these matrices with complex entries?

Comment: $*$ = transpose and conjugate, $T$ transpose. Yes, they're in $\mathbb{C}^{2x2}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, $A+A^T$ is normal if $A$ is $2\times2$ normal. The reason is that all $2\times2$ complex skew-symmetric matrices commute (because they are scalar multiples of the rotation matrix for angle $\frac\pi2$).

1. Let $A=S+K$, where $S=\frac12(A+A^T)$ is complex symmetric and $K=\frac12(A-A^T)$ is complex skew-symmetric.
2. Using the fact that $K\bar{K}=\bar{K}K$, rearrange the equality $AA^\ast=A^\ast A$ to $[S,\bar{S}] = [S,\bar{K}]+[\bar{S},K]$, where $[X,Y]$ denotes the commutator $XY-YX$.
3. Since $[S,\bar{S}]$ is purely imaginary (because $\overline{[S,\bar{S}]}=[\bar{S},S]=-[S,\bar{S}]$) but $[S,\bar{K}]+[\bar{S},K]$ is real, the rearranged equality in last step implies that $[S,\bar{S}]=0$. As $\bar{S}=S^\ast$, we conclude that $S$ is normal.

Comment: I'm interested whether in 3x3   it can be proved that skew-symmetric don't commute?

Comment: @Widawensen 3x3 *real* skew-symmetric matrices are cross product matrices, which do not commute in general.

Comment: I was thinking so that they must be somehow linked with cross product..

Comment: Where do you use that the matrix is 2x2?

Comment: @rdguez In step 2. There was a typo: in the first sentence, $KK^T=K^TK$ should read $K\bar{K}=\bar{K}K$ (now fixed), and the latter is true because $K$ is $2\times2$ complex skew-symmetric.

Comment: @user1551, do you have any result that shows that complex skew-symmetric matrices commute? Or know where to find it?

Comment: @rdguez Huh? No, it isn't that all complex skew-symmetric matrices commute (this is false in general), but that all **two-by-two** complex skew-symmetric matrices commute. It's just a simple fact, as explained by the last sentence in the first paragraph of my answer. It's so simple that I don't think anyone would state it as a theorem or lemma.

Comment: Yes, sorry, i meant two-by-two [...] matrices. Ok, thank you!

Comment: One more thing, in step 3, why you say $\overline{S}=S^*$? And why you use always the conjugate $\overline{S}$ instead of transpose and conjugate $S^*$.

Comment: @rdguez $S$ is symmetric. Therefore $S=S^T$ and $\bar{S}=\overline{S^T}=S^\ast$. And before the last line, we are talking about whether a matrix is real or purely imaginary. This has nothing to do with transposes.